# myBatis "SELECT" fails with uppercase tablename on Linux

Tags: mariadb, mybatis, identifier, case-sensitive, tablename

I have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename` (
..
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I run a query via myBatis (as defined in the mapper.xml-file):

```
SELECT .. FROM `tablename`;
```

This query fails with

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'databasename.TABLENAME' doesn't exist
```

How can I force myBatis to query with the specified lowercase name "tablename" instead of doing an uppercase-translation?

I found this: https://mybatis.org/generator/configreference/table.html where it is said, that myBatis gets the info on how to deal with case sensitivity from the database itself.
So I checked with

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

the settings and got:

```
lower_case_file_system OFF
lower_case_table_names 0
```

This means if I understand https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-case-sensitivity/ right, that the database indicates that the tablenames are case sensitive. Why does myBatis then force to given lowercase names to uppercase before issuing the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MyBatis does not change SQLs like that. Please specify versions of MariaDB, driver and MyBatis.

Comment: I did a query with lower case "tablename" with HeidiSQL and was fine and did with upercase "TABLENAME" and failed with same message.
MyBatis 1.3.2
MariaDB 5
jdbc: mariadb-java-client 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, completely my fault. Had changed my code and committed - but not pushed. So my changes in the mapping.xml did not become active in deployment.
The query, the way I had described above works.

Comment: Please delete the Question as not being useful to others.